# Decompose an image into Sinusoidal Gratings using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

"Any 2D image can be decomposed into a unique set of sine gratings".

How can I decompose my image into sine gratings?

And how can I plot some of these gratings on screen?

Comment: You need to look up "Fourier transform".

Comment: of course FFT is required but the issue is how to plot some of grating images. @nkjt

Comment: You may want to look at :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform#Multidimensional_DCTs and to:http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/dct.html

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes i thin it is helpful... But what if I wanted to show different sinusoidal grating images?